# Display all movie list using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i have a database

```
-movie ( movie_id , title , year)
          1      , thor , 2017
          2      , deadpool,2018    
-genre ( genre_id , genre_name )
              1      , action
              2      , adventure
              3      , comedy    

-movie_genre ( movie_id , genre_id )
                     1     ,    1
                     1     ,    2
                     2     ,    2
                     2     ,    3
```

my php code is

```
<?php 
$info_query = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
  FROM movie
     , genre
     , movie_genre 
 WHERE movie.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id 
   AND genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id
")or die(mysql_error());
$info_count =mysql_num_rows($info_query);
while($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info_query)){
    if ($info_count > 0){ ?>
        <?php echo $info_row['title'] ?>
        <?php echo $info_row['genre'] ?>
        <?php
    }  } 
?>
```

the output is

```
thor action thor adventure
```

and i want

```
thor acton adventure
deadpool adventure comedy
```

Comment: We stopped using this archaic, insecure, and deprecated API a long time ago. Is this for historical interest?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$info_query = mysql_query("
    SELECT mv.movie_id, mv.title, gr.genre_name
    FROM movie_genre mg
    INNER JOIN movie mv ON mg.movie_id = mv.movie_id
    INNER JOIN genre gr ON mg.genre_id = gr.genre_id
")or die(mysql_error());

$info_count = mysql_num_rows($info_query);

if ($info_count > 0) {
    $movies = [];
    while ($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info_query)) {

        if (!isset($movies[$info_row['movie_id']])) {
            $movies[$info_row['movie_id']] = ['title' => $info_row['title'], 'genres' => []];
        }

        $movies[$info_row['movie_id']]['genres'][] = $info_row['genre_name'];
    }

    foreach ($movies as $movie_id => $movie ) {
        echo $movie['title'] .' ';
        foreach ($movie['genres'] as $genre) {
            echo $genre . ' ';
        }
        echo "\n<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score -2):

This query should work:

```
SELECT title, 
GROUP_CONCAT(genre_name) AS genre
FROM movie_genre 
JOIN movie ON movie.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id 
JOIN genre ON genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id 
GROUP BY title
```

Then in php if you so wish you could replace the comma's with spaces as follows;

```
<?php 
echo $info_row['title'];
echo str_replace(',',' ',$info_row['genre']);
?>
```

Comment: See me edit using `GROUP_CONCAT` , it should be what you are after, misread the question at first and on mobile

Comment: now it says  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPERATOR ' ') FROM movie_genre JOIN movie ON movie.movie_id =movie_genre.movie_' at line 1"

Comment: Try SEPERATOR with a comma instead then, or is it imperative that they are space seperated?

Comment: i don't know i tried but it's not happening BTW i am newbie

Comment: I'm not at my PC, when I am, I will get back to you with a full working example